# SQL Server - Group By, Average and Percentiles

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

I have a FormSummaries table in SQL Server with the following relevant columns of example data:

```
FormName | CompletionTime
Form1    | 70
Form1    | 20
Form1    | 30
Form1    | 40
Form1    | 80
Form1    | 60
Form1    | 90
Form1    | 10
Form2    | 30
Form2    | 40
Form2    | 80
Form2    | 90
Form2    | 40
Form2    | 1000
Form2    | 120
Form2    | 70
```

What I need to do is:

1) Group the data by the form's name and an average of the completion time for that form, easy enough:

```
SELECT 
    FormName, AVG(CompletionTime) 
FROM 
    FormSummaries 
WHERE 
    CompletionTime  is not null
GROUP BY
    FormName
```

2) Get the average of the top 25%/bottom 25% of completion times for each form type (i.e. the average fastest and slowest 25% of time taken to complete each form). Ideally this would be in one query i.e.

```
FormName | Bottom25%AverageCompletionTime | Top25%AverageCompletionTime
Form1    | 85                             | 15
Form2    | 560                            | 35
```

I live in the real world and realise that may not be possible so separate queries for the top and bottom would be fine i.e.

```
FormName | Bottom25%AverageCompletionTime
Form1    | 85                            
Form2    | 560                           

FormName | Top25%AverageCompletionTime
Form1    | 15
Form2   | 35
```

I've looked at Partition by, Ntile and Over but I can't seem to be able to get anything to produce the desired result (though that may well be because I'm not implementing these correctly!).

Can anyone help please?

Many thanks.

Comment: in your first query, you do not need  'WHERE CompletionTime  is not null'  , since AVG will ignore nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTILE Ranks the results in chunks, so you are interested in quarters, so use NTILE (4) to split into 4 groups, and partition over the formname.  To do this with 2 queries, try

```
-- top 25%
SELECT  formname, AVG(CompletionTime) 
FROM
(SELECT 
    FormName,completiontime, NTILE(4) over (partition by FormName order by completiontime) as QuartPercentile
FROM 
    FormSummaries
WHERE CompletionTime IS NOT NULL )
    x
WHERE  QuartPercentile = 1
GROUP BY formname

-- bottom 25%
SELECT  formname, AVG(CompletionTime) 
FROM
(SELECT 
    FormName,completiontime, NTILE(4) over (partition by FormName order by completiontime) as QuartPercentile
FROM 
    FormSummaries 
WHERE CompletionTime IS NOT NULL)
    x
WHERE  QuartPercentile = 4
GROUP BY formname
```

Or with one query

```
SELECT  formname,AVG( case when QuartPercentile = 4 then CompletionTime else null end)   as [Bottom25%AverageCompletionTime]
, AVG( case when QuartPercentile = 1 then CompletionTime else null end)   as [Top25%AverageCompletionTime]
FROM
(SELECT 
    FormName,completiontime, NTILE(4) over (partition by FormName order by completiontime) as QuartPercentile
FROM 
    FormSummaries 
WHERE CompletionTime IS NOT NULL)
    x

GROUP BY formname
```

Bear in mind that if your completiontime column has integers, AVG will return an integer, so you may want to convert to get the required precision,eg

```
AVG( case when QuartPercentile = 1 then cast(CompletionTime AS decimal(9,2))  else null end)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. However, I did find that, when running the Top 25% query, all of the values in the CompletionTime column were null. I ran the inner select on its own and could see that null values were being returned. I added in where CompletionTime is not null and this now works perfectly.

Comment: I didnt realise that NTILE includes null values and assigns them to a chunk of records, but I just found this link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1508622-391-1.aspx  I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE + PIVOT:

```
;WITH PercentCount AS (
SELECT  FormName,
        COUNT(*)/4 as [Bottom25Percent],
        COUNT(*) as [Top25Percent]
FROM Forms
GROUP BY FormName
), FormsWithRowNumber AS (
SELECT  f.FormName,
        f.CompletionTime,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.FormName ORDER BY f.CompletionTime) as rn
FROM Forms f
), final AS (
SELECT  f.FormName, 
        f.CompletionTime,       
        CASE WHEN f.rn between 1 and [Bottom25Percent] THEN 1 
             WHEN f.rn between [Top25Percent]-[Bottom25Percent]+1 and [Top25Percent] THEN 2
             ELSE 0 END as [TopBottom]
FROM FormsWithRowNumber f
INNER JOIN PercentCount p
    ON p.FormName = f.FormName
)

SELECT *
FROM final
PIVOT (
    AVG(CompletionTime) FOR TopBottom IN ([1],[2])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
FormName    Top25%AverageCompletionTime Bottom25%AverageCompletionTime
Form1       15                          85
Form2       35                          560
```